# Finding differences in queries using two criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I'm trying to find a way to find a way to compare two queries that use a combine sent of criteria. In this case we have Prefixes (Two letter code like DA) and Pack number 1234567. In the query I've created a field that combines these two things so it appears 1234567DA this is done with each of the queries from the separate tables they are pulled from. The idea is that if this is in one table and not the other it would show up as "False". I tried to use an Unmatched query but that doesn't seem to work. What I have currently is as follows:

```
SELECT
    [1LagoTest].Prefix, 
    [1BigPicPackPref].BigPicPP,
    IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False") AS Compare,
    [1LagoTest].RETAIL,
    [1LagoTest].MEDIA
  FROM 1LagoTest
  LEFT JOIN 1BigPicPackPref 
    ON [1LagoTest].[Prefix] = [1BigPicPackPref].[BigPicPP]
  WHERE (((IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False")) Like "False") 
    AND (([1LagoTest].MEDIA) Not Like "*2019 FL*"))
  ORDER BY [1LagoTest].RETAIL;
```

Right now it will show whats missing from LagoPP but doesn't give me anything from missing packs in BigPicPP. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: I guess I should mention I'm not great with SQL and I haven't used Intersect and Except. I'm looking into them now though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm 100% following. Some sample data and an expected result would be good to include. A full outer join might also be what you want. It would Look something like SELECT NZ(A.SomeField, B.SomeField), CASE WHEN A.SomeField IS NULL OR B.SomeField IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS Compare FROM TableA A FULL OUTER JOIN TableB ON A.SomeField = B.SomeField

Comment: So there are a set of prefixes DA, DB, DM, DF, DT and DU. In these prefixes we have pack numbers (The same pack number can be in different prefixes). We have two sources we need to check these packnumbers+Prefixes. One is Lago the other is our BigPic files. I'm trying to run a query that shows which pack+prefix is missing from each source. So if pack 1234567DA is missing from BigPic it will show as false. and vise versa for Lago.  Hopefully that helps but let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This gets a little tricky in Access without `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but the general idea to is replicate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` using `UNION ALL`, then filter from that.

Something like this:

```
SELECT I.Prefix,
       I.BigPicPP,
       I.Compare,
       I.Retail,
       I.Media
FROM (SELECT L.Prefix, 
             B.BigPicPP,
             IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False") as Compare,
             L.Retail,
             L.Media
      FROM 1LagoTest L
      JOIN 1BigPicPackPref B ON L.Prefix = B.BigPicPP
      WHERE L.Media NOT LIKE "*2019 FL*"

      UNION ALL

      SELECT L.Prefix, 
             B.BigPicPP,
             "False", --Missing records from 1BigPicPackPref
             L.Retail,
             L.Media
      FROM 1LagoTest L
      LEFT JOIN 1BigPicPackPref B ON L.Prefix = B.BigPicPP
                                 AND L.Media NOT LIKE "*2019 FL*"
      WHERE B.Prefix IS NULL

      UNION ALL

      SELECT B.Prefix, 
             B.BigPicPP,
             "False", --Missing records from 1LagoTest
             L.Retail,
             L.Media
      FROM 1LagoTest L
      RIGHT JOIN 1BigPicPackPref B ON L.Prefix = B.BigPicPP 
                                  AND L.Media NOT LIKE "*2019 FL*"
      WHERE L.Prefix IS NULL
     ) AS I
```

You only need `IFF` in the first part of the union because in the second two parts one side will always be `NULL`, so we know the compare will always fail and be `False`.

You shouldn't need this part of your current `WHERE` clause at all `(((IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False")) Like "False")`.  But if you only want to see `False` records, just add `WHERE I.Compare = "False"` to the bottom of the outer select.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I attempted to use your code but it's giving me an error on the FROM saying that there is a syntax issue. Any thoughts? It looks okay to me.

Comment: @Deke Hmm I don't see any syntax errors either... Can you run each of the inner queries separately without error?  Or the whole inner `UNION` without error?

Comment: nothing I do seems to clear out the "Syntax error in From clause". Could it be because this is referencing two other queries instead of tables?

Comment: @Deke I'm not sure honestly.  Try wrapping the table/query names in brackets `[ ]`, maybe Access doesn't like names that start with numbers.

Comment: yeah that didn't work either. I'll keep playing with it. Access is very temperamental.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the "Unmatched" query (assuming through the Wizard) does not work, is because you are attempting to see the values of two separate tables / queries that do not match either table / query. This is not how the "Unmatched" works. All that will give you is a single table / query that does not match another single table / query.

This can most likely be done any number of ways, but this would probably get you where you want to be (or close to it):

```
SELECT 
    a.Prefix, 
    b.BigPicPP,
    IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False") AS Compare,
    a.RETAIL,
    a.MEDIA
FROM [1LagoTest] a 
LEFT JOIN [1BigPicPackPref] b ON a.Prefix = b.BigPicPP
WHERE a.MEDIA Not Like "*2019 FL*"
AND b.BigPicPP IS NULL
ORDER BY a.RETAIL
UNION 
SELECT 
    a.Prefix, 
    b.BigPicPP,
    IIf([BigPicPP]=[LagoPP],"True","False") AS Compare,
    a.RETAIL,
    a.MEDIA
FROM [1LagoTest] a 
RIGHT JOIN [1BigPicPackPref] b ON a.Prefix = b.BigPicPP
WHERE a.MEDIA Not Like "*2019 FL*"
AND a.Prefix IS NULL
ORDER BY a.RETAIL
```

NOTE: Depending on the data structure, the `ORDER BY` may cause some issues.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I’ll give these a go when I get back to work and report back. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hey guys still not working. Still only showing what is missing between LagoPP and  BigPicPP not what is missing from BigPicPP. Strange thing is I can't seem to reverse this with a secondary query that just swaps them either. I even added a test record it should find and flag as "False" and it seems to ignore it.

Comment: @Deke The query I proposed works for me (as I would expect it to) on test data. Would you mind sharing some sample data points (or examples) and edit your question to add them? Also, your desired results from that data would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I got this to finally work was to build two separate queries. One looking at what was missing from Lago and One that was looking at what was missing from BigPic. It was the only way I could get it to give me both sets of missing data. If I can find a better way to do it through one query I will report back as I'm still gonna play around with it.